# error: operator=() does not handle self-assignment properly

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I am running `clang-tidy` on the code below:

```
BinaryTree& operator=(const BinaryTree &bt){ 
    if(this == &bt){ 
        return *this;
    } 
    if(_root != nullptr) { 
        delete _root; 
    } 
    _root = new node(nullptr, bt._root->_data); 
    copy_con(_root, bt._root); 
    return *this; 
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error: operator=() does not handle self-assignment properly.
```

This is strange, since my code does handle self-assignment in the first line!

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your code seems to handle that clang-tidy error as described on their docs site: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone-unhandled-self-assignment.html

Comment: The issue here is not self-assignment, but exception safety. If `new` throws in this code, target will end in invalid state, loosing previous value and not getting a new one. It could be clang-tidy just giving wrong error.

Comment: Unrelated to the clang-tidy error. `root_ = new node(nullptr, bt._root->_data);` will be a problem if `bt._root` is `nullptr`.

Comment: `if(_root != nullptr)` is not needed. You can delete pointer unconditionally.

Comment: Unrelated: This might be a good candidate for [Copy and Swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: In my experience, when `if(this == &bt) { return *this; }` is necessary to protected from self-assignment probably means the routine doesn't maintain object coherence & invariance correctly.  (Self-assignment is unusual, so it doesn't warrant optimization this way.)

Comment: Updated link to llvm doc: https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/bugprone/unhandled-self-assignment.html (one from @scohe001 didn't work anymore).